# Is it possible see the value returned in c++?

Tags: c++, list, return

So..I'm testing a function with assert: (The value of pBola1 is 1)

```
assert(BomboTest.TreureBola(1)==pBola1);
```

BomboTest.TreureBola it's a function that returns a random number (in this case has to return 1) of a list.

```
cBola* cBombo::TreureBola(int num)
{
    int posicio_aleatoria;

    posicio_aleatoria= rand() % (num);

    return(Boles.TreureElement(posicio_aleatoria)); 
}
```

And TreureElement it's a function that returns an element of a dynamic list knowing the position of the element that you want to extract(in this case returns 'retorn' which is 1)

```
cBola* cLlista::TreureElement(int posicio)
{
    int i;
    cBola* recorreLlista;
    cBola *retorn;
    recorreLlista=primer;
    retorn = primer;
    i=0;

    if (posicio == 0)
    {
        primer = (*primer).getSeguent();
    }
    else
    {
        // Busquem la posició //
        while(i < posicio)
        {
            recorreLlista= retorn;
            retorn = (*retorn).getSeguent();
            i++;
        }
        (*recorreLlista).setSeguent( (*retorn).getSeguent() );
    }
    numElements--;
    return retorn;
}
```

And I don't know why but the assert fails. I can see the value returned by TreureElement because I have the pointer 'retorn' but I can't know the value returned by TreureBola..There is some way to see that value returned by TreureBola in the debugger?

PD:I'm using visual studio 2010

Comment: using simplified (variable|function|class)names for example-code is usually prefered, as it makes it easier to read

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create a local

```
cBola* pTemp = BomboTest.TreureBola(1);
assert(pTemp==pBola1);
```

You could look in the dissasembly and inspect the return registry, but this seems like overkill. The above is the correct approach and others will thank you in the future, when they encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can always temporarily change

```
assert(BomboTest.TreureBola(1)==pBola1);
```

to`

```
auto tmp=BomboTest.TreureBola(1);
assert(tmp==pBola1);
```

and place a breakpoint on the first line.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a small wrapper around assert to use instead:

```
template <typename T>
void compare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
  if (lhs != rhs)
    cout << "The values were not the same! " << lhs << " vs. " << rhs << endl;
  assert(lhs == rhs);
}
```

This will still call `assert`, but first you'll get some (hopefully) useful output first.

So instead of calling:

```
assert(BomboTest.TreureBola(1)==pBola1);
```

You would call:

```
compare(BomboTest.TreureBola(1), pBola1);
```

This has an added benefit that you can place a breakpoint here and see see what TreureBola returned in the debugger, too.